# Is there a way to make notifications center always visible on mac?

Tags: mac, macos, notifications

Is there a way to setup the notification center stays visible until closed manually i.e. via keyboard shortcut?

For example, if I’m using a calculator I sure don’t won’t to open/close the thing for each calculation.

Comment: if you're using the calculator that much, why not just launch it instead of using the notifications version?

Comment: If I’m using a calculator.app why should I bother having it in the notification center in the first place? Sorry, but you’re not helping me.

Comment: the answer is below - it's not possible, afaik. My 'help' was a suggestion that if you need something a lot, why bury it in a temp window.

Comment: When people ask questions as Tetsujin has. It is to get more information or offer an alternative. Which in the end may help them help you. As innate as it may seem it is valid question to understand why this other options may not work for you and possible explore.

Comment: OK, I understand. Thanks for your explanation(s). The problem with the notification center is it’s dissappeareance on the first focus lost, so it’s not necessarily the question of whether I use something often or not. Any information that needs to be transferred/copied from it somewhere else will require double opening it eventually, which is inefficient (but would be still faster than having an app opened, IF it could be open/closed manually).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that it is possible, unless you manage to go into the Notification Center code on the computer and edit it to keep it open even when clicking off of it.